# C# convert ApplicationSettings to a interface class in runtime

Tags: c#, .net-4.6.1

during migration of .net framework from 4.6 to 4.6.2 on VS 2015 for one of the web related projects ran into the following problem.

The application settings are split into 2 for testing and production.
The switch used to happen in run time based on value of key value pair in a ini file.

Additional properties were added in run time by passing values from a different process.

The conversion into interface was simple by simple assignment.

For ex:

```
IInterface sInterface = Properties.Settings.Default;
```

Unfortunately this doesnt work any more after upgradation to .net 4.6.2.

Ends up with the error : cannot implicitly convert type "Properties.Settings.Default" to IInterface.

Explicit casting doesnt work either. 
Tried following:

```
System.Convert.ChangeType ended up with System.InvalidCastException.
```

Any way this can be done?

Comment: Why are you doing it the complex way? XML Transforms were invented for this very scenario. ASP.NET had them since ancient times, but they've (relatively) recently been added to desktop projects too.

Comment: That statement does not make any sense whatsoever, the bigger question is how it could have ever worked before.  Use source control to lookup the change history on the project's Properties/Settings.Designer.cs file to find the team member that's been editing this auto-generated file.  Handing out the proper amount of lashes is up to you.

Comment: haha Thanks for your input .. will have to change the implementation..:)